# An sh syntax error

Tags: c++, linux, sh

I am executing this string which is not literally what is below, it is generated.. in C++ using system.

```
   /root/sendEmail -t me -f me -u 'Report ' -m 'List:
    Process id:26783 Cpu usage:52.8 Command:perl-ewhile(2) {print 9}
    Process id:3535 Cpu usage:23.6 Command:konsole [kdeinit] -session 10c579426f000130356953700000033
    Process id:2428 Cpu usage:0.513 Command:postgres: wal writer process
    Total cpu usage:78.5

Regards
Your  program
' -s 192.168.0.11
```

I get an error
h: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
What is wrong? All I know if command is empty, I do not get this error.

Comment: You have to escape your newlines with a backslash.

Comment: Can you show us the content of this `sendEmail` thing?

Comment: NO, I do not have it, couple days I did not have this error, I am not sure what is changed.. It does not seem to have any significance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string contained character with acii code 0 that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use newlines in your command, you need to escape them with `\`
So:

```
/root/sendEmail -t me -f me -u 'Report ' -m 'List:\
    Process id:26783 Cpu usage:52.8 Command:perl-ewhile(2) {print 9}\
    Process id:3535 Cpu usage:23.6 Command:konsole [kdeinit] -session 10c579426f000130356953700000033\
    Process id:2428 Cpu usage:0.513 Command:postgres: wal writer process\
    Total cpu usage:78.5\

Regards\
Your  program\
' -s 192.168.0.11
```

Comment: No, you don't need \. It's quoted.

Comment: Ohw, didn't know that. I'm sorry.